# Need to get gift card Id or gift card code from order id

Tags: magento2

I need to get a gift card Id or gift card code from order id.
Need to match the data between `giftcards_card` & `sales_order_item`.

Basically, I need to upload data from `live_giftcards_card` like recipient email, recipient name, order id, etc to the `sales_order_item` table inside `product_options` column.

Here `live_giftcards_card` is table of M1 & `sales_order_item` is table of M2